# Python - extract lines between multiple instances of the same delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I have a file like this

```
===
aa
bb
===
aa
cc
dd
==
11
```

I need to extract the lines between the "===" and put them in different variables (a list maybe).

Can you please help me?
Thank you

Comment: duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474216/python-to-extract-data-from-a-file

Comment: No, not quite, because I do not need the delimiters, I just need what is between them put in different variables

Comment: what do you mean by *what is between them in different variables*? Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    result = input_file.read().split('===\n')
print result
```

Comment: You should probably strip the equal signs from the beginning and end. Also split the extracted data into sublists.

Comment: Fixed it for you Rob.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to group lines between the `===` and add them to a dictionary.

```
from itertools import groupby,count

with open("in.txt") as f:
    cn = count()
    d = {}
    for k, v in groupby(f, lambda x: not x.startswith("=")):
        if k:
            d[next(cn)] = "".join(v)
{0: 'aa\nbb\n', 1: 'aa\ncc\ndd\n', 2: '11'}
```

Presuming you have at least one `=` separating each section.

Or use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) changing the key when we find a line starting with `=`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

with open("in.txt") as f:
    cn = count()
    d = defaultdict(str)
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("="):
            key = next(cn)
        else:
             d[key] += line
print(d)
defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {0: 'aa\nbb\n', 1: 'aa\ncc\ndd\n', 2: '11\n'})
```

Either way will avoid reading all your file into memory at once. If you want to remove the newline use `line.rstrip`

If you want each line as an individual element in the lists:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

with open("in.txt") as f:
    cn = count()
    d = {}
    for k, v in groupby(f, lambda x: not x.startswith("=")):
        if k:
            d[next(cn)] = list(map(str.rstrip, v)) 

print(d)
{0: ['aa', 'bb'], 1: ['aa', 'cc', 'dd'], 2: ['11']}
```

And finally if you want a list of lists:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    print [list(map(str.rstrip, v)) for k,v in groupby(f, lambda x: not x.startswith("=")) if k]
    [['aa', 'bb'], ['aa', 'cc', 'dd'], ['11']]
```

Comment: Links for the OP [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

Comment: It looks more complex, but it's very well structured. I chose the other answer basically because it was easier to use in my case. Thank you for taking the time to answer this :)

Comment: @user2493988, no worries, for a small file reading it all into memory is fine but usually reading all the file into memory is not good practice. When you want to create variables dynamically a dict is usually the way to go.

Comment: Yes, in my case it's a small file, nothing fancy. I am a ... noob at python, so I'm trying to do simple stuff. Thank you again