# Looking for text in logs

Tags: python

I have a new project to develop a log reader in Python 3.5 from txt files and I don't know how to start. The main goal is to extract pieces of logs (substrings) from a large and complex log txt file and display it in a structured way on a webpage. Would be possible please any help with libraries and commands in order to start with? I'm sorry but I'm quite new to Python. Thanks!

Comment: @GáborErdős I'm dealing with high complex logs and I'm trying to develop an structured view of it. My focus is to extract pieces of text (some times JSON) in a clean and quick view. I've been trying some pieces of code like ```m = re.search('AAXDFR [callId(.+?)}}]', text)```, but it's not working. There's a good example here ```http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474216/python-to-extract-data-from-a-file```, but I'm not able to extract substrings. Any help or opinion would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say you convert the .txt files you mentioned into a list of strings, then use a for-loop:

## for a in txt_files:

Then use some if statements to look out for keywords, and print certain messages depending on the input

using this method you could also have it look out for certain words in a certain order, by having "previous_a = a" at the end of each loop