# Python - Copying from one text file to another

Tags: python, io, copy, benchmarking, text-extraction

I'm writing a Python script, and want to copy specific lines of a Flexible I/O (FIO) data text file to my output text file.

I've tried to copy data from my data text file using [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474216/python-to-extract-data-from-a-file), but sadly, I'm not getting my ideal result. After I execute my code and I concatenate into output.txt, output.txt returns nothing and not the text lines of cpu or lat (usec) from data.txt.

Here is my code to obtain data.txt:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import os

cmd = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "fio", "--filename=/dev/sdg", "--name=test1", "--ioengine=libaio",
    "--bs=4k", "--rw=read", "--iodepth=32", "--runtime=10"],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn = os.setpgrp)

f = open("logfile.txt", "w+")
g = open("logs.txt", "w+")

f.write(cmd.stdout.read().decode())

with g as f:
    for line in f:
        # finds the leading text in the text file that tarts with "", and also removes all
        # leading and trailing spaces from a strin.
        if line.strip().startswith("lat (usec)") or line.strip().startswith("cpu"):
            # adds items to end of list
            g.write(line + "\n")
```

Here is my data text file (data.txt):

```
test1: (g=0): rw=read, bs=4K-4K/4K-4K/4K-4K, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
fio-2.16
Starting 1 process

test1: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=9401: Tue Jul  2 14:28:30 2019
  read : io=4066.2MB, bw=416418KB/s, iops=104104, runt= 10001msec
    slat (usec): min=1, max=2650, avg= 7.75, stdev=41.93
    clat (usec): min=19, max=2790, avg=298.85, stdev=180.63
     lat (usec): min=101, max=2792, avg=306.59, stdev=181.00
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[  105],  5.00th=[  112], 10.00th=[  118], 20.00th=[  120],
     | 30.00th=[  129], 40.00th=[  137], 50.00th=[  153], 60.00th=[  454],
     | 70.00th=[  474], 80.00th=[  490], 90.00th=[  502], 95.00th=[  516],
     | 99.00th=[  548], 99.50th=[  580], 99.90th=[  756], 99.95th=[  932],
     | 99.99th=[ 1592]
    lat (usec) : 20=0.01%, 100=0.01%, 250=51.56%, 500=36.57%, 750=11.76%
    lat (usec) : 1000=0.06%
    lat (msec) : 2=0.04%, 4=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=18.48%, sys=38.28%, ctx=16300, majf=0, minf=40
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=100.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.1%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued    : total=r=1041149/w=0/d=0, short=r=0/w=0/d=0, drop=r=0/w=0/d=0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: io=4066.2MB, aggrb=416417KB/s, minb=416417KB/s, maxb=416417KB/s, mint=10001msec, maxt=10001msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  sdg: ios=16094/0, merge=0/0, ticks=14376/0, in_queue=14368, util=99.01%
```

Now I expect lines 8, 15, and 18 from the data text file into the output text file, but it's returning nothing. This is what the output text file would look like (output.txt):

```
     lat (usec): min=101, max=2792, avg=306.59, stdev=181.00
    lat (usec) : 250=5.09%, 500=67.38%, 750=23.29%, 1000=3.87%
  cpu          : usr=18.48%, sys=38.28%, ctx=16300, majf=0, minf=40
```

Is there a similar way of extracting data from my data text file into my result output file using the tutorial above?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please post the code you already have, so we can analyze how to improve it. Further, please post a specific question that you want to get solved. Which lines do you want to get copied? How would you, as a human, recognize which the correct lines are? Please specify in more detail.

Comment: @mstewart Please don't machine scrape fio's human readable output - there are a number of ways it can backfire (see this [Brendan Gregg video about the perils of scraping fio output](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vm1GJMp0QN4#t=17m48s))! Instead can you use fio's JSON output (or at a stretch its CSV output) - https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_man.html#cmdoption-output-format ?

Comment: @Anon Thaks for the tip! I changed this file a lot and ended up using JSON output to access specific content from fio's output.

Comment: @mstewart You're welcome! I know it's a subtle point but it will save a lot of "what's going on?" questions later...

Comment: @Anon That is very true, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem, thank you @AlessioM and @pkfm for your help!

Here is my answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import os

def fioCall():
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "fio", "--filename=/dev/sdg", "--name=test1", "--ioengine=libaio",
    "--bs=4k", "--rw=read", "--iodepth=32", "--runtime=10"],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn = os.setpgrp)

    f = open("data.txt", "w+")
    f.write(cmd.stdout.read().decode())
    f.close()

def copyFiles():
    with open("data.txt") as f:
        with open("output.txt", "w") as f1:
            for line in f:
                if line.strip().startswith("lat (usec)") or line.strip().startswith("cpu"):
                    f1.write(line)

def main():
    fioCall()
    copyFiles()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and here is the output I obtained (output.txt):

```
     lat (usec): min=161, max=10624, avg=458.78, stdev=148.10
    lat (usec) : 250=5.09%, 500=67.38%, 750=23.29%, 1000=3.87%
  cpu          : usr=17.24%, sys=63.28%, ctx=81571, majf=0, minf=40
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
with open("/tmp/log.txt") as f:
        to_keep = []
        for line in f:
                if line.strip().startswith("lat (usec)") or line.strip().startswith("cpu"):
                        to_keep.append(line)
        print(to_keep)
```

btw: not really the cleanest way of doing it, but I guess the simplest one (in python)

even simpler would be using simple linux commands, something like:

```
   cat log.txt | grep "lat (usec)"
```

Comment: I'm about to leave work, but I'll try this tomorrow. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Additionally, if you were to use unix tools (i.e. cat and grep), you can manage them with [subprocess.popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen).

Comment: Hi @pkfm, thanks for the tip, but I am not able to use unix tools for this script.

Comment: Hi @AlessioM, your code helped, as I don't get any errors anymore, but when I run the code, the resulting log file is still blank. EDIT: Removed link